# How to make a UITextField not respond?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I want to make a UITextField so that when I touch it, it runs a certain method, then if the conditions are correct (which are tested within that method), it will run its normal 'bring up the keyboard' method. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a delegate for your UITextField

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

Then within the delegate, implement:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (condition) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```